# Calculating weight from multiple means

Tags: average, means

I have encountered this question on my quiz today.

The question is

**Mean annual salary of all employee is 20000
Mean annual salary for male is 22000
Mean annual salary for female is 17000
What is the percentage of female in the company?**

I feel like this is a weighted average question but i can't seem to figure out the way to solve this question.

Comment: What do you know about weighted averages? Try to write things down and identify what the weights correspond to and how to translate each pieces of information you have.

Comment: Introduce some variables and set up some equations, and then solve them.  For example suppose there are $m$ men and $w$ women and $t$ total employees.  What is total salaries for men? women? employees?  can you then find $\frac{w}{t}$?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry) for the advice.

Here is my solution.

22000M + 17000F = 20000(M+F)

22000M + 17000F = 20000M + 20000F

2000M = 3000F
2/3 = f/m

f = 2/5

f = 40%

I believe that this is correct.